# MS SQL management studio 2014 некорректно работает MS SQL Server 2008r2

Tags: sql, sql-server

Почему-то не полностью работает функционал.

На сервер зайти могу, выполнить запрос могу и т д, но например удаленно перезагрузить сервер(Ошибка: RPC недоступен) или открыть Activity монитор я не могу, вылетает ошибка.

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

С 2012 студией таких проблем не было.

**UPD**:

Ошибка при попытке вызвать Activity Monitor такая:
The Activity Monitor is unable to execute queries against server [ServerName].
Activity Monitor for this instance will be placed into a paused state.
Use the context menu in the overview pane to resume the Activity Monitor.

Aditional information:
Unable to find SQL Server process ID 1820 on server [ServerName]
(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.ResourceMonitoring)

Answer (score 2):

Это не ошибка работы 2014 студии с 2008R2 сервером в целом, а ошибка конкретно вашего окружения.

По ошибке с RPC - попробуйте запустить данную службу на сервере БД.

UPD:
По проблеме с Activity Monitor ответ взял отсюда:
https://serverfault.com/questions/141849/activity-monitor-is-unable-to-execute-queries-against-server

Сам ответ: проверьте, что существуют счетчики производительности SQL Server'а в Системном мониторе. Если они не существуют, вручную переустановите их, запустив следующие команды из под командной строки с правами администратора:

```
cd \windows\system32
lodctr /R
```

Comment: Пополнил ответ.

Comment: Вы пополнили вопрос, а ответ пополню я :)